# uint8_t * to integer and string

Tags: programming, c++

**Convert text array/buffer to integer and string.**

hi! i'm sending text to an arduino and the output of that library is a 
uint8_t array.

Atm the text send is a number between "0" and "1023"

```
void something(uint8_t * text){
 analogWrite(13,text);// does not work
}
/*
toInt() also not
int() not
atoi() not
invalid conversion from 'uint8_t* {aka unasigned char*}' to 'const char*'
*/
```

i need to convert it to an  integer or better to a uint16_t.

As i plan to send custom commands in near future it would also be good to know how to convert that array to a string, that i then split/manipulate/parse.. whatever.

i looked in various posts but i couldn't get it to work on that simple example above. i'm new to c++

if it's needed the length is also aviable inside the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are storing your text in an *unsigned* pointer (`uint8_t *`)instead of a *signed* pointer (`char *`).

If you change all your text types to `char *` then you can directly use `atoi()`.  If you have a lot to change, though, you can just *cast* the unsigned pointer into a signed one (and make it `const` at the same time):

```
analogWrite(13, atoi((const char *)text));
```

Comment: its from a websocket lib... i would need to rewriter the whole lib...anyway this worked perfectly

Comment: btw i will update this analogwrite at 60Hz . is "cast" slow/are there faster ways to convert the buffer to a string or int?

Comment: @cocco Cast makes no difference at runtime, only compile time.  There are faster ways to convert than atoi, but they aren't as safe - i.e., they don't do any bounds checking.

Comment: it works but i have a bigger problem now. it crashes really fast. i can't send data faster than 2 times per second. maybe you know more about this.http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17811/esp8266-websockets

Answer (score 0):

analogWrite is a function to set a PWM duty cycle value to a pin on the micro

Usually to control a motor speed or LED brightness or similar.

Unless you plan to use the char value to set the PWM value??

A bit more context would help with your problem.

Comment: i control a led with websockets. now it works. @Majenko answered it correctly

Comment: This isn't really an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I've converted first four bytes to string, and then to int :

```
void something(uint8_t * payload){
String str="";
char c;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    if (isDigit(c=(char)(*(payload+i))))
        str += c;

int Val =str.toInt();
Val=Val>1023?1023:Val;

analogWrite(14,Val);
}
```

Comment: This is a very inefficient approach.